# Segmentation fault assigning std::string in a struct

Tags: c++

the following code results in a segmentation fault when it's run and I can't figure out why:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

struct Token
{
  int num;
  string val;
};


int main()
{
  Token* tok = (Token*) malloc (sizeof(Token));
  tok -> val = "myval";
  std::cout<<tok->val;
}
```

see backtrace:

```
0  0x00007ffff7b95d9b in std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6;
1  0x0000000000400867 in main ()
```

Comment: One question: what is the reason for using dynamic allocation here? If you don't have a good answer for that, then you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `malloc` in C++ code, it's rarely the correct choice.

Your options are:

```
Token tok;
tok.val = "myval";

auto tok = std::make_unique<Token>(); // C++14
tok->val = "myval";

auto tok = std::unique_ptr<Token>(new Token()); // C++11
tok->val = "myval";

auto tok = std::make_shared<Token>(); // C++11, use if resource is shared
tok->val = "myval";

Token* tok = new Token();
tok->val = "myval";
delete tok;
```

These options should suffice for most cases.

Prefer the options from top to bottom: The default way should be creating objects, then `unique_ptr`, then `shared_ptr` and only if absolutely necessary you should deal with raw pointers.

The reason for that is easy: Exception safety and memory leaks. An object cannot be leaked, you can't forget to `delete` a `unique_ptr` or a `shared_ptr`, but you can with a raw pointer. Additionally, the raw pointer won't ever get deleted in case of an exception. `unique_ptr` should be preffered to `shared_ptr` because `shared_ptr` has overhead (an atomic counter to make it thread safe).

Demo that everything compiles fine (without C++14 make_unique): [Demo](http://ideone.com/8iotTW)

Answer (score 6):

`malloc` does not call any constructors. Try using `new` and it should work fine.

Also don't forget to `delete` it afterwards, or either use smart pointers or directly put the variable on the stack.

Comment: and `delete` for releasing memory

Comment: Or just instantiate the object automatically.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's why you cannot use malloc with std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411815/how-to-use-a-c-string-in-a-structure-when-malloc-ing-the-same-structure):

> You can't malloc a class with non-trivial constructor in C++. What you
>   get from malloc is a block of raw memory, which does not contain a
>   properly constructed object. Any attempts to use that memory as a
>   "real" object will fail.

As well as (already pointed out in other answers):

> The problem is that malloc does not call the constructor of example.
>   Since a string is usually represented as a pointer on the stack, this
>   is set to zero, and you dereference a null pointer. You need to use
>   new instead.

If you insist on using malloc, you can either use placement new (see the link for details) or just use a plain ol' `const char*`:

```cpp
struct Token
{
  int num;
  const char* val;
};

int main()
{
  Token* tok = (Token*) malloc (sizeof(Token));
  tok->val = "myval";
  std::cout << tok->val;
  free(tok);
} // will not seg fault
```

Comment: Using `char *` is a really bad idea for this case. You then have to manually manage the memory for it as well.

Comment: @Ivan Can you elaborate?

Comment: A `char *` is just a pointer - you still have to allocate the memory it will point to and then deallocate it as appropriate.
It's for the same reason that you can't just write `Token* tok;` and expect it to be a fully functional object.